# Why does the Python Socket program stop working when converted to an exe file?

Tags: python, sockets

I have written an online chess app, using Python  and Sockets. When I run the server and connect the clients, everything runs perfectly smooth. However, when I convert the client into an exe file and run it, the client isn't able to connect to the server anymore.

I have also tried to convert the server into an executable and it stopped working either. I think it has problems with the command server.listen(), because the ouput is only [STARTING] Server is starting... (More details in the server side code below)

Has anybody encountered problems too, when converting a socket app into an exe file? I didn't get any results with a Google search.

Shortened client side code:

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
NONE_MESSAGE = "!NONE"
OPPONENT_DISCONNECTED = "!OPPONENT_DISCONNECTED"
SERVER = "192.168.56.1"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)


def send(client, msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)


def recieve(client):
    send(client, NONE_MESSAGE)
    msg_length = client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg_length:
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = client.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg != NONE_MESSAGE:
            return msg
    return False
```

Server side code:

```
import socket
import threading
import random

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
NONE_MESSAGE = "!NONE"
OPPONENT_DISCONNECTED = "!OPPONENT_DISCONNECTED"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def recieve(conn):
    send(conn, NONE_MESSAGE)
    msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg_length:
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg != NONE_MESSAGE:
            return msg
    return False


def send(conn, msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    conn.send(send_length)
    conn.send(message)


def get_opponent(addr):
    for c1, c2 in client_pairs:
        if c1 == addr:
            return c2
        if c2 == addr:
            return c1
    return None


def handle_client(conn, addr):
    global new_client
    global new_client_name
    name = recieve(conn)
    if new_client:
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected to {new_client}")
        client_pairs.append((new_client, addr))
        color = random.choice(['w', 'b'])
        send(conn, color+new_client_name)
        if color == 'w':
            messages_to_send[new_client] = 'b'+name
        else:
            messages_to_send[new_client] = 'w'+name
        new_client = None
        new_client_name = None
    else:
        new_client_name = name
        new_client = addr
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} waiting")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        if addr in messages_to_send.keys():
            send(conn, messages_to_send[addr])
            del messages_to_send[addr]
        if addr in disconnects:
            send(conn, OPPONENT_DISCONNECTED)
            disconnects.remove(addr)
        msg = recieve(conn)
        if msg:
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                if new_client == addr:
                    new_client = None
                opponent = get_opponent(addr)
                if opponent:
                    disconnects.append(opponent)
                connected = False
            opponent = get_opponent(addr)
            if opponent:
                messages_to_send[opponent] = msg
            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")

    conn.close()


new_client = None
new_client_name = None
messages_to_send = {}
client_pairs = []
disconnects = []


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()-1}")


print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
start()
```

Comment: How exactly are you producing the exe file?

Comment: "stopped working" doesn't really say much. Was there an error message or exception stacktrace? Was it running but not progressing as expected? Did it finish executing without doing what was expected?

Comment: I am producing the exe with pyinstaller. With "stopped working", I mean that it didn't respind anymore. I think it got stuck while trying to connect to the server, because the server didn't respond.

Comment: had same issue with pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Please Wireshark the traffic and provide a screenshot(or a PCAP file). My guess is that some kind of firewall is blocking the connection, but not sending back an RST packet like a good firewall would.

Edit: If you find a firewall in the path, create a temp rule that allows connections. Eventually you will need to make it more secure, but doing it temporarily is OK.